# Probability at least one card is hit [Texas hold'em]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poker

The cards in hand = [9][9]. 
The question is as follows:

What is the probability we hit at least one 9 on the flop, turn or river (so, on the next 5 cards)?

There are (50, 5) = 2.118,760 board combinations and two outs [9][9] left.

P(at least one 9) means the following:

```
(i) P(hitting exactly one 9);
(ii) P(hitting exactly two 9's);
```

And combine those probabilities.

```
ad (i):
p(How many boards have exactly one 9)?
(49, 5) / (50, 5) = 0.9
1 - 0.9 = 10% 
ad (ii):
p(How many boards have exactly two 9's)?
(48, 5) / (50, 5) = 0.8
1 - 0.8 = 0.19%
```

Combining the probabilities

```
p(one 9) + p(exactly two 9's) * 1 - p(one 9) 
= .10 + .19 * (.10)
= .119%
```

So the probability of hitting at least one 9 is 11.9%. Is this correct?

Comment: There is something wrong in your calculation, indeed the number of boards with exactly one 9 is $2\binom{48}{4}$ (for each 9 we can choose 4 cards among 48) and the number of boards with exactly two 9 is $\binom{48}{3}$.

Comment: Note that 11.9% is almost the probability to set at the flop $$1-\frac{48*47*46}{50*49*48}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a pair of 9 in hands, the probability that a 9 not occurs on the flop, turn and river, assuming that we only know these two cards in hands, is given by

$$\frac{48}{50}\frac{47}{49}\frac{46}{48}\frac{45}{47}\frac{44}{46}$$

thus the probability that we hit at least one 9 on the flop, turn or river is

$$1-\frac{48}{50}\frac{47}{49}\frac{46}{48}\frac{45}{47}\frac{44}{46}\approx 19.2 \%$$

With a direct calculation we have that

- the number of boards with one 9 is given by $2\binom{48}{4}$
- the number of boards with two 9 is given by $\binom{48}{3}$

thus the probability that we hit at least one 9 on the flop, turn or river is

$$\frac{2\binom{48}{4}+\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{50}{5}}\approx 19.2 \%$$

Comment: Can your equation be reframed as 1-((48, 5)/(50, 5)) as it gives ≈ 19.18

Comment: @Bondeaux yes of course since (48,5)/(50,5) is the probability of boards without 9!

Comment: Btw, if you don't mind having a go at another problem. What should be the probability of hitting trips on a board of 5? So let's say we have in hand [K][9], what is then the chance at least two [9][9] comes on a board? Is it (48, 3)/(50, 5)?

Comment: @Bondeaux you can use a similar method to the direct method here presented, let formulate a new OP, I will answer to it!

Comment: I will, hold on please ;')!